# Enabling Paging with x86

Tags: c, paging, qemu

I'm trying to enable paging in a c function where I use inline assembly to set cr3 and cr0 registers. However, the registers are not being set and I'm not sure why. Also my c program is running on qemu and I have no idea how to debug with that. Here's my code:

```
void vmm_on(void) {
    __asm__("mov 0x200000, %eax\n\t"
            "mov %eax, %cr3\n\t"
            "mov %cr0, %eax\n\t"
            "or %eax, 0x80000000\n\t"
            "mov %eax, %cr0");

}
```

Comment: How do you know that does not work, that registers are not set?

Comment: You are mixing up your AT&T and Intel syntax. That does not do what you think it does. (The biggest issue, the `or` instruction is or-ing the value in eax with the value in memory at 2GB. eax is not modified)

Comment: old topic , but with qemu , you can add the option ' -d int ' (without the quotes) to display the values of your registers.

Answer (score 2):

I think (from your code snippet), you got the purpose of cr0 and cr3 wrong. You have to do a couple of thing in order to setup paging properly. First thing is, you've to setup a page tables properly ie. page directory, page tables, page frames. Then, you've to make cr3 point to that page directory address, CPU will find the address of page directory via cr3. After you've setup tables properly, then, you've to enable "paging" bits of cr0 register. Consult [this page](http://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Paging) for details.